# Is there way to solve this minesweeper without guessing?

Tags: logical-deduction, minesweeper

I have arrived at this board and I'm kinda stuck. Is there any way to continue without guessing?

[image: minesweeper board]

Comment: As @RobPratt and @JLee noted, you need 4 more mines to finish this game, but the counter reads `003`. I count a total of 95 flags, and the typical [Expert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minesweeper_(video_game)#Common_board_configurations) game has 99 mines, which suggests to me that the counter is wrong; it should say `004` instead. Maybe your Minesweeper app has a rendering bug?

Comment: Because of the incorrect counter I spent a while searching for an error in the solved parts, thinking this could be a trick question with answer "first remove this flag which was a mistake". But I agree, the counter must be wrong.

Comment: @Rufflewind: Rendering bugs can *never* give this result. It's probably due to a race condition, which is common in sloppy software.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because the left 5 needs two more mines, the remaining mine for the adjacent 3 must be in the top right cell.

Also, that same 3 uses up all three mines indicated by the counter, and that leaves nothing to cover the bottom two remaining cells, so you must have an error elsewhere.

Answer (score 10):

As RobPratt pointed out, you can mark the flag highlighted in green below:

[image]

However, you will have to guess, because there are **4** boards (thx for the correction, aschepler) that satisfy the conditions that you have:

[image]

Comment: 4 boards. But it's still the case that each of the remaining six unknown cells has probability 1/2 of containing a mine.

Comment: From your two valid boards, the flag above or below the leftmost 5 can change independently of the other three flags.

Comment: @aschepler Ah! I see now. I totally missed that. I will edit my post. thx

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4HAdZGq (which you can use if you want)

Comment: Yes, my mistake (but on an originally covered square). I see you've already posted a correct image.

Answer (score -1):

Mines in the top middle (above the 3), along with immediately below that same 3, and the bottom left seem to validate all constraints, and use only 3 mines as indicated as remaining on the counter.

Comment: That handles the top 3 but doesn't leave any mines for the bottom two 3s.